# in php, a function's arguments can be a word without quotes or $

Tags: php

I always thought that the arguments of a function in PHP should be either a string enclosed by '', or a number, or a variable.

However, looking at this in php.net's manual I see:

```
   public function baz(Test $other)
```

What does the word Test here refer to?

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5 supports "[type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)" for object or array parameters.  If `$other` is not a `Test` object, there will be a runtime fatal error.

So make sure you catch the hint.